# How to display active session in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, session, session-storage

I want to display all active sessions list for different devices that is from which devices user is logged in to application like Facebook/Gmail. Anyone have idea about how can achieve this in angular 7?

Comment: This is not an Angular issue, rather a backend one. Only the server can know where a user is logged in (as long as you create that feature), so the only way the Angular app can know is by asking the backend.

Comment: Thanks @WillAlexander for your quick response.